# Parse.com Querying for object containing array of pointers not working with include

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

With below code:

```
var Photo = Parse.Object.extend("Photo");

 var query = new Parse.Query(Photo);
 query.equalTo("owner", Parse.User.current());
 query.limit(1000);
 query.descending("takenAt");
 query.include("galleries");

 query.find({ 
   success: function(results) {
     // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a winning record
     console.log(results);
     res.render("photos", { photos : results,user:Parse.User.current(),nav:req.originalUrl });
   },
   error: function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
 });
```

I get error: {"code":102,"message":"field galleries cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object"}

This galleries field is an array of pointers.  An example from the data browser: [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Gallery","objectId":"hXFwm8yrRT"}]

I have found numerous posts saying this should be correct - Why is it not working?

Comment: This answer pretty clearly states that this should be possible: https://www.parse.com/questions/fetch-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

I was looking deep into the data and found that some objects had null values inside the array.  Since these null values are indeed not pointers to Parse Objects, the Parse servers apparently reject includes if any requested array of pointer fields contain null values in the array.

Not a very graceful error, and would be nice to have this behavior shown in the documentation.

I hope this helps someone who might have a similar issue in the future.

Comment: did you happen to find a solution to figure out how to catch the "null" objects? When i checked for nullity by doing if(obj != null), it wouldn't work. Any ideas?